# Rholang matching with AND and RevAddress

Tags: rholang

Rholang supports pattern matching with the and operator `/\`
So, the following code to only accepts an integer.

`for (value /\ Int <- channel) { ... }`

Is there something similar for REV addresses?

`for (revAddress /\ ???? <- channel) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REV addresses are strings in rholang. There is no REV address type to match. Since REV addresses always start with "1111" the best you can do is check to see if the string starts with "1111"

```
match  address.slice(0,4)  {
   "1111" => { return!("got a rev address") }
   _ => { return!("did not get a rev address") }
}
```

or

```
if ( address.slice(0,4) == "1111" ) doSomething
```